Rollback Transaction in Mysql Query
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE ExecuteDataFill(IN p_internalCompanyId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE u_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name, address, area, pincode, city, state, state_code, country,
               pan_number, gst_number, bank_name, account_number, ifsc_code,
               phone_number, role
        FROM user_data;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        DECLARE p_name VARCHAR(225);
        DECLARE p_address VARCHAR(225);
        DECLARE p_area VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE p_pincode VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE p_city VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_state VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_state_code VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE p_tin VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE p_country VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_pan_number VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_gst_number VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_bank_name VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_account_number VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_ifsc_code VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_phone_number VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE p_latest_org_external_id VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE p_role VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE p_returned_sqlstate CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
        DECLARE p_message_text TEXT DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE p_mysql_errno INT DEFAULT 0;

        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            p_returned_sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            p_message_text = MESSAGE_TEXT,
            p_mysql_errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;

        -- Log the error
        SELECT CONCAT('Error: ', p_returned_sqlstate, ', Message: ', p_message_text, ', MySQL Error: ', p_mysql_errno) AS Error_Message;

        -- Rollback the transaction
        ROLLBACK;

        -- Return the error details
        SELECT
            p_returned_sqlstate AS RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            p_message_text AS MESSAGE_TEXT,
            p_mysql_errno AS MYSQL_ERRNO;
    END;

    -- Start the transaction
    START TRANSACTION;
    OPEN u_cursor;

    read_loop: LOOP
        -- Fetch the next row
FETCH u_cursor INTO p_name, p_address, p_area, p_pincode, p_city, p_state,p_state_code,p_country, p_pan_number, p_gst_number, p_bank_name, p_account_number,p_ifsc_code, p_phone_number, p_role;

        -- Exit the loop if no more rows
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        BEGIN
            -- Insert into users table
            INSERT INTO users (username, name, whatsapp_number, created_by, updated_by, code, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (p_phone_number, p_name, p_phone_number, p_internalCompanyId, p_internalCompanyId, '', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

            -- Insert into procedure_log
            INSERT INTO procedure_log (log_message) VALUES ('Inserted user: ' || p_name);
        END;

    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE u_cursor;
    COMMIT;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

This stored procedure will insert the data into SQL users table.
I am trying to rollback all the insert queries if anyone of them in the cursor breaks?
I tried a few other options for rollback all the transactions, but it does not rollback the whole transaction if there is a mysql error encountered.
Now, my problem is:

How will this affect the data calling the rollback transaction inside the loop?
Will it read all the lines again and send it to the server for insertion or it will just read the row where it fails during the execution?

I need some advice. Thanks

Your current setup has a few issues, primarily with the cursor handling and the use of DECLARE inside the EXIT HANDLER, and use the CONCAT function for string concatenation.
The below query will might resolve the issue.
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE ExecuteDataFill(IN p_internalCompanyId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE p_name VARCHAR(225);
    DECLARE p_address VARCHAR(225);
    DECLARE p_area VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE p_pincode VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE p_city VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_state VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_state_code VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE p_country VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_pan_number VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_gst_number VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_bank_name VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_account_number VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_ifsc_code VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_phone_number VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE p_role VARCHAR(10);

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        DECLARE p_returned_sqlstate CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
        DECLARE p_message_text TEXT DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE p_mysql_errno INT DEFAULT 0;

        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            p_returned_sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            p_message_text = MESSAGE_TEXT,
            p_mysql_errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;

        -- Log the error
        SELECT CONCAT('Error: ', p_returned_sqlstate, ', Message: ', p_message_text, ', MySQL Error: ', p_mysql_errno) AS Error_Message;

        -- Rollback the transaction
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    -- Start the transaction
    START TRANSACTION;

    -- Declare the cursor
    DECLARE u_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name, address, area, pincode, city, state, state_code, country,
               pan_number, gst_number, bank_name, account_number, ifsc_code,
               phone_number, role
        FROM user_data;

    -- Declare the NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN u_cursor;

    -- Read the data from the cursor
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH u_cursor INTO p_name, p_address, p_area, p_pincode, p_city, p_state, p_state_code, p_country, p_pan_number, p_gst_number, p_bank_name, p_account_number, p_ifsc_code, p_phone_number, p_role;

        -- Exit the loop if no more rows
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        BEGIN
            -- Insert into users table
            INSERT INTO users (username, name, whatsapp_number, created_by, updated_by, code, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (p_phone_number, p_name, p_phone_number, p_internalCompanyId, p_internalCompanyId, '', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

            -- Insert into procedure_log
            INSERT INTO procedure_log (log_message) VALUES (CONCAT('Inserted user: ', p_name));
        END;

    END LOOP read_loop;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE u_cursor;

    -- Commit the transaction
    COMMIT;
END;;

DELIMITER ;


this is giving error for cursor declaration You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE u_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name, address, area, pincode, city, s' at line 43
